# Processing form data with a Python CGI Script

Tags: python, html, forms, cgi

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong here. I have two scripts, one for the form and the other for the processing. It looks correct but after two hours of staring at it I cannot see where I am going wrong.
Here are the two scripts, they are very short so please take a look at it.

The Form:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import cgi
import cgitb



print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print("")

print'''<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marks Sonitus Practice</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Practice">
    <meta name="author" content="CGI Practice">
</head>
<body>
<form action="process_data.py" method="post">
    <html><span> First &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
    <input type="submit" name ="submitname" value="Submit Name"></form>
</body>
</html>'''
```

The script to process the form:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable(display=0,logdir="/var/www/cgi-bin/error-logs")

file_name = "/var/www/cgi-bin/practice/process_practice.py"
f = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(file_name))
try:
    open(f)
except:
    print"This file could not be found!"
form = cgi.FieldStorage(f)
firstname = form.getvalue('firstname')
print firstname
```

Can anyone show me where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: Sorry I should have said - when I run this script it prints None. No error, nothing in the error log files, just None.

Comment: "*when I run this script it prints None.*" - Precisely, how are you running the script?

Comment: @rob I run it from the terminal with python nameoffile.py

Comment: CGI scripts are intended to be invoked by a web server in response to a networked HTTP requesst. If you want your script to run, you'll need to deploy a web server and configure it to invoke your programs. A simple web server is available via this command: `python -mCGIHTTPServer`.

Comment: @rob I have set up my development environment to run my cgi scripts and have configured my apache2.conf file. It works fine and runs my cgi scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thats simple in your form replace the `action=process_data.py`to 
`action=http://localhost/cgi-bin/practice/process_practice.py` or may be `action=http://localhost/cgi-bin/practice/process_data.py` whatever the name of that script is.

Answer (score 1):

Changing it from:

```
action=process_data.py
```

to:

```
action=http://localhost/cgi-bin/practice/process_data.py
```

Worked.